# android no icon in title bar

Tags: android, xml, styles, icons

I tried to add the launcher image to the customised title bar of my android app, but it doesn't appear when I run the app.

Here is my code for the customised style:

**customised_style.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <style name="CustomWindowTitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.WindowTitle">
      <item name="android:textSize">20dip</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#e7f4fb</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 </style>

 <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
       <item name="android:background">#b5b1b4</item>
       <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>

 </style>


 <style name="CustomWindowTitle">
      <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomWindowTitleText</item>
      <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
      <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
      <item name="android:shadowRadius">7</item>
      <item name="android:shadowColor">#e32020</item>

  </style> 


  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
       <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
       <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitle</item>
       <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
  </style>
```

and here is the custom app defined in the android manifest file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javapapers.android.sqlitestorageoption"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


        <application 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.javapapers.android.sqlitestorageoption.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.javapapers.android.sqlitestorageoption.NewAnimal"
                android:label="" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.javapapers.android.sqlitestorageoption.EditAnimal"
                android:label="" >
            </activity>
        </application>
```

Can anybody figure out what I am missing so that I can correct the error and run the app with the icon ?

Comment: try this example : [How to create a custom titlebar](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bit late for the answer but add this line to the theme

`<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>`

this might be the reason that your code is not working. in new devices runnig HC and ICS, the action bar is whats up there.